# React Native map crashes only with apk but not in local

Tags: react-native, google-maps, apk

when use google map my apk crash but in local run correctly in react native expo. in apk when go to screen apk crash

What is actul issue and how can resolve that issue

Answer (score 1):

You should check the native log of your release build with:

npx react-native log-android

We can't know the issue with these informations only.

Comment: can i use in react native expo

Comment: Yeah I guess. Let me know